# Some simple limit question

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Let $\{a_n\}$ be a sequence of positive numbers. If $$\lim_{n\to\infty} n^2a_n = 0,$$ what (if anything) can be said about the series $$\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n\,?$$

If $$\lim_{n\to\infty} na_n = 0,$$ what (if anything) can be said about the series?

Comment: Do you mean "sequence", or do you want to add the terms?

Comment: I think he means the series $\sum a_n$, c.f. my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

In the first case we can say that $\sum a_n$ converges. Indeed, by the convergence of $(n^2a_n)$ we deduce the existence of a $K$ such that for all $n$, $a_n \leq \dfrac{K}{n^2}$ and so the series $\sum a_n$ converges by comparison.

In the second case we can say nothing. Indeed, put $a_n:= \dfrac{1}{n \log(n)}$. Then $na_n \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, but $\sum \dfrac{1}{n \log(n)}$ doesn't converge.